# Ubuntu 17.04 - install Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text

Recently searched for a newer version of Ubuntu - 17.04. At once, there appeared some strange prolems with him. I'm not a Linux spec, I installed it to teach it anyway; I ask. I do not know how to solve it. Now: I'm trying to install Sublime Text 3. Upgrading to Ubuntu (16.04.2 LTS) I installed it with:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```

Now when I use the same commands I get errors in the terminal. Here is the log:

```
dawid4157@lenovo:~$ sudo su root
[sudo] password for dawid4157:
root@lenovo:/home/dawid4157# sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
Sublime Text 3 Installer: the package in this PPA downloads and installs the latest Sublime Text 3 beta builds.

For more info, see: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/0[...]ubuntu-ppa-now-available.html
More info: https://launchpad.net/~webupd[...]archive/ubuntu/sublime-text-3
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmpe9vkcs9v/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: /tmp/tmpe9vkcs9v/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key C2518248EEA14886: public key "Launchpad VLC" imported
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg: imported: 1
OK
root@lenovo:/home/dawid4157# sudo apt-get update
Pobieranie:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security InRelease [89,2 kB]
Stary:2 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Stary:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Stary:4 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates InRelease
Stary:5 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports InRelease
Błąd:6 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/dev/ InRelease
Could not resolve host: download.sublimetext.com
Pobrano 89,2 kB w 30s (2918 B/s)
Czytanie list pakietów... Gotowe
W: Nie udało się pobrać https://download.sublimetext.com/apt/dev/InRelease Could not resolve host: download.sublimetext.com
W: Nie udało się pobrać niektórych plików indeksu, zostały one zignorowane lub użyto ich starszej wersji.
root@lenovo:/home/dawid4157# sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
Czytanie list pakietów... Gotowe
Budowanie drzewa zależności
Odczyt informacji o stanie... Gotowe
Zostaną zainstalowane następujące NOWE pakiety:
sublime-text-installer
0 aktualizowanych, 1 nowo instalowanych, 0 usuwanych i 0 nieaktualizowanych.
Konieczne pobranie 0 B/9566 B archiwów.
Po tej operacji zostanie dodatkowo użyte 26,6 kB miejsca na dysku.
Prekonfiguracja pakietów ...
(Odczytywanie bazy danych ... 202898 plików i katalogów obecnie zainstalowanych.)
Przygotowywanie do rozpakowania pakietu .../sublime-text-installer_3126-2~webupd8~1_all.deb ...
Downloading...
--2017-07-10 15:09:10-- https://download.sublimetext.[...]text_3_build_3126_x64.tar.bz2
Resolving download.sublimetext.com (download.sublimetext.com)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘download.sublimetext.com’
download failed
Download done.
Removing outdated cached downloads...
sha256sum mismatch sublime_text_3_build_3126_x64.tar.bz2
Sublime Text is NOT installed.
dpkg: błąd przetwarzania archiwum /var/cache/apt/archives/sublime-text-installer_3126-2~webupd8~1_all.deb (--unpack):
podproces nowy skrypt pre-installation zwrócił kod błędu 1
Wystąpiły błędy podczas przetwarzania:
/var/cache/apt/archives/sublime-text-installer_3126-2~webupd8~1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? I have permission to **opt** directory as something.

Comment: Problem is with the server you download from not with Ubuntu or your setup. I can't reach "https://download.sublimetext.com" either (`wget  https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-pub.gpg` errors out)

Comment: So what should you do to install Sublime Text 3?

Comment: Wait for the server to come back alive?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `add-apt-repository`, you can add the repository's address and key manually by performing the following commands in a root shell. b.t.w. when opening a root shell in Ubuntu or any other Debian based distribution, use the following command

`sudo -s`

and insert your root password at the prompt.

To add the repository manually, try the following

```
wget -qO - https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

Comment: works fine for me.

Comment: @ninjamaker does it work for you too now?

Comment: @Rinzwind Did not work. Same time. I give the log. Additionally, I noticed that I can not normally download from sublime-text page this

Comment: I can download each repository. The Atom was downloaded without problems.

Answer (score 1):

After doing `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3`

do `rm -f /etc/apt/trusted.gpg` as quickfix from [here](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2017/07/msg00224.html)

then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

It will ask for confirmation to install it without verification. Once the Debian developers have debugged the problem the issue will be sorted soon.

Comment: Doing this may break other application updates that rely on gpg